# Elastic data node with shield

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

but it can't working after I setup shield

I added user to elastic by command

```
shield/esusers useradd es_admin -r admin
```

This is my master node config

```
cluster.name: vision
node.name: "node_master"
node.master: true
node.data: false
discovery.zen.ping.multicast.enabled: false
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["192.168.1.5"]
path.logs: /var/elastic/log
path.data: /var/elastic/data
```

This is my data node config

```
cluster.name: vision
node.name: "node_data"
node.master: false
node.data: true
discovery.zen.ping.multicast.enabled: false
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["192.168.1.5"]
path.logs: /var/elastic/log
path.data: /var/elastic/data
```

How can I connect data node to master node?

Answer (score 0):

There is no extra work you need to do to join data and master node to form a cluster.It treats both type of nodes same.
Your hosts setting is mentioning only one host.

```
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["host1:port","host2:port"]
```

Each node will keep pinging the hosts listed above until both are initialized.Adding the local host is of no harm to array as ping wont fail but help in automated deployement of elasticsearch on multinode ecosystem.
since you are using shield make sure if you enabled ssl for node communicatioon then also specify the path to SSL keystore files.